# Remainder of Taylor expansion of function at random point

Tags: probability, probability-theory, statistics, taylor-expansion

Given a function $f: \mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}$, we can write its Taylor expansion about the point $m$ as
$$
f(x) = f(m) + \nabla^T f(m) (x-m) + \frac{1}{2} (x-m)^TH_f(m)(x-m) + o(\|x-m\|^2),
$$
where $H_f(m)$ is the Hessian of $f$ evaluated at $m$. I am interested in the case where $X$ is a Gaussian random vector with mean $\mu$ and covariance $\Sigma$, then plugging in we get
$$
f(X) = f(\mu) + \nabla^T f(\mu) (X-\mu) + \frac{1}{2} (X-\mu)^TH_f(\mu)(X-\mu) + \text{Rem}_f(X, \mu).
$$

What is the correct characterization of the remainder term? Clearly it is going to be a random variable, and intuitively it should be upper bounded (in probability) by
$$
\text{Rem}_f(X, \mu) \le \|X-\mu\|^3 \sup_y \|D^{(3)}f(y) \|_{\text{op}},
$$
where the supremum is being taken over $y$ which is a point between $\mu$ and $X$, so the domain is random.

I am looking for a more rigorous expression or a reference to a text/notes that cover such issues. Generally speaking, in the statistics literature this kind of thing comes up under 'delta method' but in those cases you are dealing with a statistic (like the sample mean), and so the remainder can be dealt with by saying it vanishes at some rate as the sample increases. Here I am trying to characterise $f(X)$ where $X$ is a single random vector.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Taylor formula with integral remainder yields
$$Rem_f(x,\mu) = \int_0^1 (1-t)^2 D^3f(\mu+t(x-\mu))(x-\mu,x-\mu,x-\mu)\mathrm{d}t.$$
Hence
\begin{eqnarray*}
|Rem_f(x,\mu)| 
&\le& \int_0^1 (1-t)^2 |D^3f(\mu+t(x-\mu))(x-\mu,x-\mu,x-\mu)|\mathrm{d}t \\
&\le& \frac{1}{6} \max_{0 \le t \le 1} ||D^3f(\mu+t(x-\mu))|| \times ||x-\mu||^3.
\end{eqnarray*}